# Irish Degree Terminology

Tags: application, faculty-application, international, ireland

I'm from the US looking at an academic job in Ireland, and I'm not sure what the form below is asking for. It has a field for "qualification" and also for "result/class of award". If qualification is for the level of degree earned (masters, PhD, etc.) what does "result/class of award" mean?

[image: Screenshot of the application page]

It seems like [this site](http://www.nfq-qqi.com/) might have something to do with the answer, but it only mentions "Class of award-type".

Comment: https://www.scholaro.com/pro/Countries/Ireland/Grading-System may help

Comment: I found that, but I wasn't sure if it was relevant, since it doesn't use the same language as the application. It also seems to mainly apply to grade conversions for classes, whereas I the application seems to be describing something that would apply to a degree.

Comment: Not an answer, but in the UK for instance, university undergraduate degrees are awarded including a class: “first-class honours” comes to mind. This wouldn’t be relevant for PhDs, of course, but it wouldn’t be the first time that an online form isn’t quite optimised… see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_undergraduate_degree_classification

Comment: That would make sense, there are bachelors degrees in the dropdown menu, but it is odd that that "result/class of award" is a required field, since the most relevant degree for this position is a PdD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form is asking for "Result/Class of award". So, if you are filling it in for an undergraduate degree, you would write the corresponding class (described below).

For a Master's or PhD, you can write the *result*, i.e. Pass/Merit/Distinction for a Master's, and perhaps something like pass with no corrections/minor corrections/major corrections for PhD. Since it's a free text box you can word this however you want. I notice there is also a comment box provided at the end where you could give more details about your specific qualification (perhaps PhD GPA, if you have that -- I'm assuming you studied in the USA).

Undergraduate degrees in the UK and Ireland follow a classification system by which percentages are assigned a class:

- 70% and above: first class
- 60 -- 69%: second class upper division, or 2:1 (pronounced "two-one")
- 50 -- 59%: second class lower division, or 2:2 ("two-two")
- 40 -- 49%: third class
- 35 -- 39%: pass (some universities do not have this category)
- below 35%: fail

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. It seems that not all North American universities have as rigorous a process for defending a thesis and it depends a lot on the discipline/program.